# $A$ is positive semidefinite and $a_{pp} = a_{qq} = a_{pq} = \alpha $ $\mathop \Rightarrow \limits^? $ $pth$ and $qth$ rows of $A$ are identical

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $n ≥ 2$ and suppose that $A = [a_{i j} ] \in M_n$ is positive semidefinite and there are
distinct $p,q \in \{ 1,...,n\} $ such that $a_{pp} = a_{qq} = a_{pq} = \alpha $.

Why are $pth$ and $qth$ rows
of $A$ identical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(e_i)_i$ be the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Note that $(e_p-e_q)^TA(e_p-e_q)=0$; since $A\geq 0$, $e_p-e_q\in \ker(A)$ and $Ae_p=Ae_q$. Then the columns of $A$ of indices $p,q$ are the same and we are done.

EDIT. Some details. 1. $(e_p-e_q)^TA(e_p-e_q)=a_{p,p}-a_{p,q}-a_{q,p}+a_{q,q}=0$.

2. Let $(u_i)_{i\leq n}$ be an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $A$ associated to the eigenvalues $(\lambda_i)_{i\leq r},0,\cdots,0$ where $\lambda_i>0$. If $x=\sum_{i\leq n}x_iu_i$ satisfies $x^TAx=\sum_{i\leq r}\lambda_i{x_i}^2=0$, then the $(x_i)_{i\leq r}$ are $0$ and $Ax=\sum_{i>r}0x_i=0$